# how to get the client ID huawei In-App Purchases

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services

how can I get the client id who Purchased the product in my app I'm using huawei In-App Purchases (IAP), flutter app

Comment: hi@oscar0, may i confirm what is the client that you are referring to? If you want to obtain user information, you may also need to use the [Account kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms/huawei-accountkit?ha_source=hms1) interface to obtain user information. The IAP requires a user to log in to the Huawei ID to perform transactions.

Comment: @oscar0 Please provide more details about your case so to help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.